# react-native GoogleSignin.signIn() doesn't work

Tags: react-native

I would like to add googleSignin on react-native.
I add the configuration and i have an error DEVELOPER_ERROR
[image]
I use an simulator android,  i don't understand.

```
render() {
    return (
    <Button
        title="Google Sign-In"
        onPress={() => this._onGoogleButtonPress().then(() => console.log('Signed in with 
        Google!'))}
     />
)}


componentDidMount() {
   GoogleSignin.configure({
        webClientId: 'id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        offlineAccess: false
      })
}

  async _onGoogleButtonPress() {
    console.log('_onGoogleButtonPress')
    // Get the users ID token
    const user = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    console.log('user', user)
  
    // Create a Google credential with the token
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(user.idToken);
    console.log('googleCredential', googleCredential)
    // Sign-in the user with the credential
    return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  }
```

I have an error with this method GoogleSignin.signIn()

The webClientId with client_type = 1  if it's correct.
[image]

Do you have exactly the same problem ?

Comment: which react native google signing package are you using ? can you share a link ? and give me info about react-native info ?

Comment: I use this package '@react-native-community/google-signin'  and '@react-native-firebase/auth'

Comment: Follow the documentation steps from both library i believe you're missing something if you will see same error again i will post a step by step process for you thanks

Comment: I think, I Have a problem with the update file java.     If i put many include settings.gradle,   I didn't see java file update.    You need a specific command to update file java ?

Comment: did you follow the react native firebase auth configuration steps for google signin or did you follow all step that mention in react native google signin. i beleive you're missing something ? please revised step it will resolve

Comment: I will restart my configuration with this websites, https://rnfirebase.io/ and it's ok. I think i install other lib and bad configuration.   Thanks @MuhammadUmairGhufran

Comment: yes. i believe you will. happy coding :)